# How to beautify html using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3 in my project.

The width of my screen is 341 pixel.

Here is html code:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default margin-bottom-10">
        <div class="panel-heading nopadding ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="panel-title pull-left">
                        <i class="ico-dark ico-rounded ico-hover ico-xs et-layers"></i>
                        select:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body padding-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">group</div>
                <select id="projectGroup" class="form-control fullwidth height-30">
                    <asp:Literal ID="litProjectGroupsOptions" runat="server" />
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Layer</div>
                        <select id="projectLayers" class="form-control fullwidth height-30">
                            <option value="0">All Layers</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="editLayer" title="הצג גנט" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" id=""></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here how it looks:

[image]

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/90426/).

I want to beautify the view:

[image]

Any idea how can I beautify the view?

Comment: What do you mean by 'beautify'? What have you tried?

Comment: The first aim of bootstrap is to scale your website to many difference screen widths. Asking us to make it work on screen of 341 pixels width is somewhat of the opposite of that. However, all you need to do is put a bit of vertical space between the elements, that shouldn't be hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `row` and `col-*`for this layout.
Bootstrap 3 supports input group component with add-on button or label at beginning or ending of input:

For add-on button:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
```

For add-on label:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
```

See sample of input group component here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/90437/

Hope this helps.